# I am not able to render my ejs file. The Tab is just loading and loading. Once I stop my nodemon, it gets rendered

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I am searching for a particular user in `app.get("/user/:U_ID)`. Below is the code for it.

```
app.get("/user/:U_ID", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.U_ID);
    User.find({_id: req.params.U_ID}, function(err, foundList) {
    if(!err) {
    if(foundList) {
        console.log(foundList);
        res.render("dashboard.ejs", {user: foundList[0]});
    }
    } else {
        // alert("Something went wrong");
        res.redirect("/");
    }
  });
});
```

I am finding that user too in my database. But I am not able to render the ejs that I want to render after finding the user from database.

[Here is the code, its output in console and my chrome tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApSYw.png)

When it reaches to the line of `res.render(...)`, it just starts to load, load and load.
When I am stopping my `nodemon` or I am again saving the `app.js` with `CTRL+S`, `nodemon` again restarts the server, then my `dashboard.ejs` gets rendered.

**Please help. How to render the `dashboard.ejs`.**

Comment: Is there any errors that are being output in the console or it just loads as you are describing with no errors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.